# Error "ld returned 1 exit status" en Dev C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Tengo un error en Dev C++, intento validar que una cadena (nombre) no este vacia y luego calcular una nota final sumadas las notas parciales. Pero no logro hacer que compile por el error "ld returned 1 exit status". Cuando el nombre sea null el programa debe parar, y si alguna nota no esta dentro de 0 y 10 vuelva a pedir otro nombre hasta completar X alumnos pero siempre hasta que un nombre sea null (se detiene el programa).

CÓDIGO

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std; 

int main(){

    /* variables

    nombre = nombre
    nota1 = n1
    nota2 = n2
    nota3 = n3

    */

    string nombre;
    int n1, n2, n3, c;
    float suma;

    c == 1;

    while (c!=0){

        cout<<"Ingrese Nombre: ";cin>>nombre;

        if (!nombre.empty()){
            cout<<"Ingrese Nota 1: ";cin>>n1;
            cout<<"Ingrese Nota 2: ";cin>>n2;
            cout<<"Ingrese Nota 3: ";cin>>n3;

            if(n1, n2, n3 > 0 and n1, n2, n3 < 10 ){

                suma = n1*0.1 + n2*0.5 + n3*0.4;

                cout<<"La nota de "<<nombre<<" es "<<suma<<endl;
            }

        }       
        else{
            c = 0;          
            cout<<"No existe alumno";               
        }       
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes varios problemas en tu código.
Primero te falta el include para poder usar la clase string.

```
#include <string>
```

Después cuando quieres hacer una asignación estás haciendo una comparación al poner el doble igual:

```
c == 1;
//debería ser:
c = 1;
```

Despues, la comprobación del if no la puedes hacer así:

```
if(n1, n2, n3 > 0 and n1, n2, n3 < 10 ){
```

debes comparar cada variable independientemente:

```
if (n1 > 0 && n2 > 0 && n3 > 0 && n1 < 10 && n2 < 10 && n3 < 10) {
```

Y por último, en mi compilador me avisaba de una posible pérdida de precisión al convertir la operación que haces y asignas a la variable suma. La variable es float, y la operación se está tomando como double. Se soluciona declarando la variable suma como double en vez de float, pero eso ya, según necesites.

Comment: hola, ya he resuelto el problema y tambien me faltaba colocar que las notas estaban fuera de rango pero, cuando ingreso una cadena vacia no se cierra el while, y no muestra la salida de "No existe alumno".

Comment: Hola de nuevo. El problema es que al hacer `cin >> nombre;` no te deja introducir una cadena vacía. Si cuando te está preguntando que introduzcas el nombre pulsas solo ENTER, no pasa nada, y sigue esperando hasta que metas algún caracter. Entiendo que eso no es lo que quieres hacer. Para qu te deje introducir una cadena vacía y luego comprobarlo en el código, debes sustituir esa instrucción por esta: `getline (cin, nombre);` Así te aceptaría espacios en blanco entre palabras en el nombre y no terminará hasta pulsar ENTER, aunque no hayas introducido ningún caracter